# how to change the xticks to a specific range

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have drawn a countplot as follows:

```
ax, fig = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(user_id_count[:100])
```

> (array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
>   15, 16,
>           17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
>           34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]), )

[image]

But I want to change the xticks to only show `10, 20, 30, 40` these 4 number, so I checked the documentation and recode it as follows:

```
ax, fig = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(user_id_count[:100])
plt.xticks(range(10, 41, 10))
```

[image]

But the xticks isn't what I want.
I have searched the relevant questions but I didn't get what I want exactly.
So if not mind could anyone help me?

Comment: what about `plt.xticks(range(9, 40, 10), range(10, 41, 10))`? The first range are the x-values of the tick-marks and the second one their labels.

Comment: @Heike you are right and this works. But if set the range out of the data, it will be a part of blank in the plot.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to define the labels on the x-axis. The `set_xticklabels` method from `matplotlib` module do the job [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html).
By defining your own labels, you can hide them by setting the label equal to `''`.

By defining your own labels, you **need to take care** that they are still **consistent with your data**.

Here is one example:

```
# import modules
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Init seaborn
sns.set()

# Your data to count
y = np.random.randint(0,41,1000)

# Create the new x-axis labels 
x_labels = ['' if i%10 != 0 else str(i) for i in range(len(np.unique(y)))]
print(x_labels)
# ['0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
# '10', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
# '20', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 
# '30', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '40']

# Create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.countplot(y)

# Set the new x axis labels
ax.set_xticklabels(x_labels)
# Show graph
plt.show()
```

[image]